# The argument type ‘Widget’ can’t be assigned to the parameter type ‘String’?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

How do I use my custom widget Notes? I unfortunately can't use the full code in the AddNoteScreen.

I got this error when I changed a few things from the class I'm taking. Below I've pasted the instructors code, with my custom widget included. I'll comment below with the other changes I tried that lead me to this error.

Custom widget down to bare bones:

```
class Notes extends StatelessWidget {

TextEditingController notesController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: notesController,  
    );
  }
}
```

```
class AddNoteScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  User user;
 AddNoteScreen({
     required this.user,
   });

  @override
  State<AddNoteScreen> createState() => _AddNoteScreenState();
  }

class _AddNoteScreenState extends State<AddNoteScreen> {

  TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController notesController = TextEditingController();
  
  bool loading = false;

    @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState(
  );
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor:Color (0xFF162242),
        elevation: 0,
      ),

      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
      new TextEditingController().clear();
    },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(children: [
              
              Text("Title", style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, 
              ), 
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 60,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: TextField(
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF192A4F),
                  ),
                  controller: titleController,
                ),
              ),


              Notes(), // My Custom Widget
            
    
              SizedBox(height: 50,),
              loading ? Center (child: CircularProgressIndicator(),) : Container(
                height: 50,
                
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  
                  onPressed: ()async{
      
                  if (
                    titleController.text == "" || notesController.text == "") // HERE
                    {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("All fields are required")));
      
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                        loading = true;
                      });
      
                      await FirestoreService().insertNote(titleController.text, notesController.text, widget.user.uid); // HERE
      
                      setState(() {
                        loading = false;
                      });
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    }
                }, child: Text("Add Note"),  
        ),),
        ]),),
        ),
      ),
      );
       }
      }
```

^ above I changed `notesController.text == ""` to `Notes == ""` and then `notesController.text` to `Notes()`

```
class FirestoreService{

  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future insertNote(String title, String notes, String userId)async{
    try{
      await firestore.collection('notes').add({
        "title":title,
        "notes":notes,
        "userId": userId
      });
    } catch (e) {}
  }
}
```

^ above I changed `String` to `Widget` for notes

```
class NoteModel {
  String id;
  String title;
  String notes;
  String userId;

  NoteModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.notes,
    required this.userId
  });

  factory NoteModel.fromJson(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    return NoteModel(
      id: snapshot.id,
      title: snapshot['title'], 
      notes: snapshot['notes'],
      userId: snapshot['userId']
      );  
  }
}
```

^ above I changed `String` to `Widget` for notes

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Notes'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Color (0xFF162242),
        actions: [
          TextButton(onPressed: () => FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(), child: Text("Sign Out", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),),
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("notes").where('userId', isEqualTo: user.uid).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
          if (snapshot.hasData){
            if(snapshot.data.docs.length > 0){
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context,index) {
                  NoteModel note = NoteModel.fromJson(snapshot.data.docs[index]);
                  return Card(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 16),
                    child: Column(
                        children: [
                          ListTile(
                           title: Center(child: Text(note.title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                           ),
                           ),
                              onTap: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EditNoteScreen(),));},
                            ),

                          
                            ListTile(title: Center(child: 
                            Container(
                              height: 300,
                              child: 
                             Text(note.notes),),), // HERE
                            ),


                    ]),
                  );
                }
              );

            }else Center(child: Text("No notes available", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),);

          }
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddNoteScreen(user: user)));
        },
        backgroundColor: Color (0xFF162242),
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

^ `Text(note.notes)` is where I get the error.

[image: debug console]

[image]

I don't really know what I'm doing but can something like this work ? Totally different answer is okay too!

I'm sorry that's a lot of code. Any help is appreciated.
Also link to the class if anyone is interested https://skl.sh/3wxeMVF

Comment: What is the exact error message?  The error message also should indicate a file and line.  Which line?

Comment: I updated my question, please take a look

Comment: The complete error log from the console would help.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the debug console

Comment: @LeenaMarie When you hover with your mouse over the red line, what error is shown in the popup? And is the class `NoteModel` the actual class you are using, because you wrote something about changing String to Widget, which I do not understand as there are only Strings and no Widget.

Comment: Added another screenshot. And I use ```NoteModel``` on the HomeScreen..? Also, I edited the instructors code to be a Widget not a String. Kept the instructors code in the question incase it would be helpful for figuring out a way to use the custom widget, because my attempt is probably way off ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumptions**

Based on the code and comments I guess the actual class `NoteModel` and `Notes` are looking something like this:

```dart
class NoteModel {
  Notes  notes;
  ... 
}

class Notes extends StatelessWidget { 
  TextEditingController notesController = TextEditingController();
  ...
}
```

**Problem**

This explains the error message `The argument type ‘Widget’ can’t be assigned to the parameter type ‘String’?`:

`Text(note.notes)` expects `note.notes` to be a String. Whereas you changed `note.notes` to be the Widget `Notes`.

**Solution 1**

The widget `Text()` expects Strings, not another Widget. Thus,
change `notes` back to a String:

```dart
class NoteModel {
  String notes;
  ... 
}
```

Build the rest of your code around this `NoteModel`, do not change it.

**Solution 2**

If you want to use

```dart
class NoteModel {
  Notes notes;
  ... 
}
```

then the Text widget would be called something like this:

```dart
Text(note.notes.notesController.text)
```

However, this is NOT recommended, as a `NoteModel` is a data model. And data models should never hold Widgets. A Widget is meant for showing data, not for holding it. A data model and a Widget serve different functions. Keep them separated.

**Firebase**

Note, that one cannot store whole Widgets (like `Notes`) in in Firebase but only Strings, Numbers etc.

(Please always post **your** current code, not code that is indirectly related related to the issue. Otherwise, people will find it very difficult to spot the problem.)